# Html.Encode class not encoding ≥ or ≤ characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an string that I need to convert it to XML and for the most part it is working for < or > but it is not for ≥ or ≤ characters.

Input string is:

> `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ≥65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

```
<span>@Html.Encode(indication.Sentence.CompiledTextTitleCase)</span>
```

Output string is:

> `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete &lt;65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ≥65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`

Any idea why this is happening any how to fix it?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. `≤` has no special meaning in HTML or XML and is not required to be encoded as an entity, as long as the character can be represented in the document's encoding (which is true for any Unicode encoding, at least).

Comment: That's normal. You can replace it by yourself by using this mappings: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_math.asp

Comment: while `<` and `>` have a special meaning in html (start/end for a tag, e.g. `<title>`), `≥`does not have any special meaning in html. This is why you have to encode the former, while the latter works as it is.

Comment: If you _really_ want to see it encoded (despite the fact it isn't really necessary) consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.htmlencode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: In your above code `Html.Encode` can be removed altogether (since it does nothing useful).

Comment: If your result is XML, your XML library (XDocument, XDoc or whatever else you use) should handle that. You should *not* do this by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while `<` and `>` have a special meaning in html (start/end for a tag, e.g. `<title>`), thers nothing special about `≥`. This is why you have to encode the former, while the latter works as it is.

Having said this `Html.Encode` will only encode those characters which *have* a special meaning and thus can be mis-interpreted when reading that data. At client-side you get this code:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete &lt;65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ≥65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

where `&lt;65` will be printed as `<`.

If you´d send the `<` un-encoded to your client you ´d get this:

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete <65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ≥65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

which isn´t valid html for the reason mentioned above.

So there´s nothing to be fixed here.

Comment: Also consider highlighting that `Html.Encode` can be removed altogether.